# Adjectives that decline as consonant stems in the neuter plural nominative/accusative

Tags: adjective, morphology, declension, third-declension

From what I have read, most third-declension Latin adjectives other than comparatives take the i-stem endings *-ī,* *ium* and *-ia* in the ablative singular, genitive plural and neuter nominative/accusative plural, respectively.

[Allen and Greenough §114-119](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-adjectives-classification-and-paradigms#fn2) discuss the general patterns, and [Allen and Greenough §121](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-adjectives-case-forms-consonant-stems) discusses *-e* vs. *-ī* in the ablative singular,  *-ium* vs. *-um* in the genitive plural, and a few other variations like *-īs* vs. *-ēs* in the masculine/feminine accusative plural and feminine nominative singular forms in *-a,* like *clienta* and *hospita.*

Adjectives that take *-a* in the neuter plural nominative/accusative appear to be even less common than adjectives that take *-um* or *-e,* though. It seems that many third-declension adjectives of one ending lack attested neuter plural forms at all (discussed to some extent in [Allen and Greenough §122](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/irregularities-and-special-uses-adjectives)).

Which third-declension adjectives have attested plural forms in *-a*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest examples of third-declension adjectives that have attested consonant-stem forms in the neuter nominative/accusative plural seem to be the following:

- the class of comparative-declined adjectives, such as neuter plural nominative/accusative adjectives ending in *-iōra* (including *maiōra/majōra*) and *minōra*
- *vetera.* It is thought that *[vetus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6651/cur-nullum-genus-adiectivo-vetus)* was originally a neuter substantive noun.
- *plūra* (despite genitive *plurium*). It seems [*pluria* was maybe a very uncommon variant form, but the typical form was *plura*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5876/plura-or-pluria). The derived word *complura/compluria* apparently exists in both forms.
- *ūbera.* Of course, this exists as a plural substantive, but according to Allen and Greenough §119, the form *ūbera* is also used as a neuter plural adjective (although the ablative singular form of this adjective is usually *ūberī*). [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uber#Adjective_2) gives "ūberia", but that form doesn't show up anywhere in the PHI Latin Texts corpus, so I'm guessing Wiktionary is just showing an incorrect declension table for this  word.

#### Dubious or less clear examples

- *pūbera.* Allen and Greenough §121d says that *pūbes* takes *-a* in the nominative and accusative plural, but I haven't found an actual example of *pubera,* so I suspect that this adjective might have been defective instead in Classical Latin. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pubes#Latin) lists the neuter plural form as "puberia", which I would guess is an erroneous auto-generated form.
- *memora.* I found *memora* listed in a grammar (*[Grammatica Anglo-Romana: Or, A Syncritical Grammar,...,](https://books.google.com/books?id=5082kcor28AC&pg=PA56)* by Samuel Shaw, 1689) as a neuter plural form, presumably of the adjective *memor* 'mindful', but I wasn't able to find any actual examples of *memora* being used as an adjective (rather than as the imperative of *memoro*) in a Latin document. As I mentioned in the question, it seems to be possible and not uncommon for third-declension adjectives of one ending to be defective in the neuter plural, so I don't particularly trust Shaw (or Wiktionary, which lists the form *memora* in its declension table for *[memor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/memor)*) to be giving an attested and not just theoretical form. (The meaning of "memor" presumably contributes to the absence or scarcity of examples of neuter usages.)

Guardia and Wierzejski (1875) include *puber* and *memor* in a list of adjectives that are defective in the neuter nominative/accusative plural (p. 133-134, *[Grammaire de la langue latine](https://books.google.com/books?id=TFdhHTcJk3EC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq="puber")*).

- *-corpora, -colora.* Another old book ("[Some improvements to the art of teaching...](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ms1lAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22complura%22+%22plura%22+%22vetera%22+%22ubera%22+%22minora%22&source=bl&ots=UbW9Jh5IIg&sig=aFVFEYoIZy338kgS6YSe9DJtcgY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiaorWdqsDbAhVLr1QKHcJxBpMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22complura%22%20%22plura%22%20%22vetera%22%20%22ubera%22%20%22minora%22&f=false)," Fifth Edition, by William Walker, 1693) mentions compound adjectives ending in *-corpora* or *-colōra,* like *bicolōra,* but Walker seems to say that these actually originated as o-stem forms (corresponding to masc. singular nominative *-corporus, -colōrus*), not as consonant-stem forms.

I found a few more mentioned in §3 of "[Declension of the Latin present participle in connection with its syntactico-semantic use](https://www.degruyter.com/dg/viewarticle/j$002fjoll.2018.17.issue-1$002fjoll-2018-0001$002fjoll-2018-0001.xml)" (2018), by Hendrik Christiaan Walvoort.

Walvoort says that in a discussion of words that can take *-i* in the ablative singular but that have plurals forms in *-a,* Priscian mentions *ludicra,* which is supposed to go with the ablative form *ludicri.* However, it seems that Priscian is the main evidence for this as a third-declension adjective; dictionary entries record instead a first/second declension adjective *ludicer* or *ludicrus.*

Walvoort also provides a citation indicating that present participles had neuter plural forms in *-a* instead of in *-ia* in rare contexts:

> Kühner and Holzweissig [...] consider the ending *-a* as a striking singularity instead of *-ia* in such phrases as *silenta loca* and *pestilenta loca.*